# R - catch file not exists in readRDS()

Tags: r

I try to load a file from a .RData file and in case it does not exist, the necessary operations (take a long time) need to be computed and the .RData file is created.

```
myVariable<- readRDS('myVariable.RData')
if (!exists("myVariable")){
  myVariable<- longTimeOperation()
  saveRDS(myVariable, 'myVariable.RData')
}
```

The problem is that if the file does not exist yet, R is aborting with the following error:

```
cannot open compressed file 'myVariable.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

This interrupts the whole process and the if is not even executed. What is a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `file.exists` function:

```
if (file.exists("myVariable.Rdata")) {
  myVariable <- readRDS('myVariable.RData')
  ...
} else { 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, this has a race condition. I don't know of a better way to do it though, unfortunately. I'm upvoting, but I wish that the designers of R didn't make everything about R so hacky because this could never be used in production code.